# Kendo grid - How to get the row details on RowSelected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

As part of Kendo grid upgrade, some of my old code seems to be not working due to change in implementation

I have used `events.Change` to trigger a row click event(Sample code below)

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.BankSearchList).Name("Grid")
                                .Events(events =>
                                {
                                    events.Change("onRowSelected");
                                    events.DataBound("onGrindBound");
                                })
```

In my `onRowSelected(e)` method, I was accessing key column member using

```
e.row.cells[0].innerHTML
```

**e.row is undefined now.** 
What is the right way to use now?
Using `events.Change` for row selected functionality the right way to do so?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

here is reference on how to get selected row detail [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qvKRk/439/) .  click on row to get its detail.

```
var gview = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
//Getting selected item
var selectedItem = gview.dataItem(gview.select());
alert(selectedItem.ShipName);
```

Comment: thanks, I am assuming making the grid .Selectable() mandatory for this to work?

Answer (score 7):

**Example - get the selected data item(s) when using row selection**

The same you can do using the html helper as well. onchange event.

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "age" }
  ],
  dataSource: [
    { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
    { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
  ],
  selectable: "multiple, row",
  change: function(e) {
    var selectedRows = this.select();
    var selectedDataItems = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
      var dataItem = this.dataItem(selectedRows[i]);
      selectedDataItems.push(dataItem);
    }
    // selectedDataItems contains all selected data items
  }
});
</script>
```

**Example - get the selected data item(s) when using cell selection**

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
function grid_change(e) {
  var selectedCells = this.select();
  var selectedDataItems = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < selectedCells.length; i++) {
    var dataItem = this.dataItem(selectedCells[i].parentNode);
    if ($.inArray(dataItem, selectedDataItems) < 0) {
      selectedDataItems.push(dataItem);
    }
  }
  // selectedDataItems contains all selected data items
}


$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "age" }
  ],
  dataSource: [
    { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
    { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
  ],
  selectable: "multiple, cell"
});
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.bind("change", grid_change);
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

I have to use events.change to fire a row click event

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.BankSearchList).Name("Grid")
                            .Events(events =>
                            {
                                events.Change("onRowSelected");
                            })
```

then handle the `onRowSelected` function as :

```
  <script> 
 var selectedRow = null;
    //onRowSelected
    function onRowSelected(e)
    {
        var row = this.select();
        if (row.length > 0 )
        {
            selectedRow = e.sender.select();
            var item = e.sender.dataItem(selectedRow);
        }
    }
</script>
```

so, the item variable contain all details you needs.

Answer (score 1):

For those with AngularJS:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    dataSource: gridDataSource,
    columns: [
        { field: 'name' },
        { field: 'phone' }
    ],
    selectable: 'row',
    change: function () {
        var selectedRows = this.select();
        var rowData = this.dataItem(selectedRows[0]);
        console.log(rowData.name + ' ' + rowData.phone);
    };
};
```

Make sure to have `selectable: 'row'` or `selectable: 'multiple, row'` in the grid options.

Answer (score -1):

```
function onRowSelected(e) {
    var gview = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    //Getting selected item
    var selectedItem = gview.dataItem(gview.select());
    var colValue = selectedItem["<columnName>"];
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what was the issue and how you solved it. Showing code is nice, explaining is even better